# How to use functions of <strings.h> like strcmp() with object of <string.h> in c++

Tags: c++, string, authentication, copy, compare

i also noticed that functions of <strings.h> does not work with the object of <string.h>

for example in dev c++

```
#include<string>
#include<strings.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
string a="admin";
string b;
cin>>b;
if(strcmp(a,b)==0)
{
cout<<"Equal";
}
}
```

so the compiler shows error at line where strcmp() function is being called.

```
[Error] cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int strcmp(const char*, const char*)'
```

what does this error actually means and how to solve this problom to make a login menue.

**please help me to solve this problom**

**i also know the alternate mathod to use c type string as follows, that is working fine**

```
   #include<strings.h>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
    char user[32]="admin",u[32]="";
    char password[32]="admin",p[32]="";
    cout<<"\nLOGIN>>\n\nEnter User Name:";
    cin.getline(u,32);
    cout<<"Enter Password:";
    cin.getline(p,32);
    if(strcmp(u,user)==0 && strcmp(p,password)==0)
    {
cout<<"Match";
}
}
```

**But i want to compare the objects of <string.h>,not an array.**

Comment: What's wrong with just using `a == b`?

Comment: What is `strings.h`? C only contains `string.h` or in C++ you should use `cstring` (without extension)

Comment: Note that cstring is the c++ version of string.h from the C programming language. C has no `std::string`, so the ability of C functions to interact with a `std::string` is limited.

Comment: thank you so much sir a==b is working fine.i did not know that

Comment: sir can we copy these strings using assignment operator?

Comment: @AwaisKaleem a [good documentation page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) will list all of the functions and overloaded operators of a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strcmp` operates on c-strings, not std::strings.

To access the internal c-string of an std::string, use the [c_str() method](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/).

i.e.

```cpp
if (strcmp(a.c_str(), b.c_str()) == 0) {
 // ...
}
```

But you can also [do the comparison directly](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operators/)

```cpp
if (a == b) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: thank you so much sir.

Comment: sir can we copy strings using assignment operator?

Comment: @AwaisKaleem Yes. Unless you are move-assigning. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator=/

Answer (score 0):

This is because the function `strcmp()` asks the programmer the parameters:

```
const char *, const char *
```

But you're trying to pass the arguments like:

```
std::string, std::string
```

But the function expects the `const char *`.

To solve that, you need to use `.c_str()` after the `std::string`.

Try this way:

```
if (strcmp(a.c_str(), b.c_str()) == 0)
```

This will convert the entire `std::string` object to `const char *` type.

Use this when you must need to use `strcmp()` or a function that needs `const char *` type. Otherwise the recommended way is given below.

---

You don't even need to use `strcmp()` since `std::string` has comparison operator, so that you may evalulate the same expression as:

```
if (a == b)
```

It'll become true if the string object `a` is equal to `b`.

Comment: `c_str()` converts nothing in modern C++. It merely provides access to the `std::string`'s internal buffer. Even in older C++ implementations that didn't provide the internal buffer were so rare that I don't think I ever saw one.

Comment: @user4581301 maybe you've seen just now then.

Comment: thank you so much sir

Comment: @RohanBari I've finally managed to get all of my company's C++ code up to at least C++11 over the past year. I'm safe.